# Django asking me to migrate pending migrations on server again and again?

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, deployment

Hello everyone my project is too small , I have only one app with name `accounts` with custom  user model and i'm trying to deploy that on heroku server. But django showing me some weird behavior on server. I dont know how to describe my problem because its quite strange behavior i have never seen it before.

im making migrations

```
heroku run python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

then i'm migrating it.

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

Then i try to create a user by

```
heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser

**You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.        
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.**

Username:
```

Where you can see migrations are still unapplied....What is this problem ?

Comment: I'm going through same problem, tell me if you get some solution.

Comment: I'll take an educated guess: Are you using SQLite?

Comment: nope i'm using postgrez

Comment: Are you entirely sure? Please show your `DATABASES` (leave out passwords if you have any there).

Comment: @Chris the problem was with heroku , Actually i got to know heroku has limit on creating new apps and i had created so many times new app on heroku so my limit reached to its end ,So i just created new heroku account with my new gmail and created my new app and i deploy there and my app is now deployed but there is a problem i'm facing now with static files -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783856/how-to-load-static-files-on-heroku-server Please check this question i hope you can answer